# Declaring a custom appender in Log4j.xml file

Tags: log4j

I have written a custom appender so how do i declare it in Log4j.xml file.

```
My property file is[custom appender is in org.copofi.common.logging.SystemStatusAppender] :

    log4j.rootLogger=INFO,logfile,console,SystemStatus
    log4j.logger=INFO,logfile,console,SystemStatus

    # Console appender (stdout)
    log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%p] <%t> [%X{jsessionId}] [%c] %m%n

    # File appender
    log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
    log4j.appender.logfile.File=${catalina.base}/logs/copofi.log
    log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%p] <%t> [%X{jsessionId}] [%c] %m%n

    log4j.appender.SystemStatus=org.copofi.common.logging.SystemStatusAppender
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="false" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">`    

<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
            <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a zzz} %-5p %F.%M:%L: %m%n"/>
            </layout>

            <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
                <!-- only the levels (comma separated) specified in LevelToMatch will be logged -->
                <param name="LevelToMatch" value="DEBUG, WARN,INFO,ERROR, FATAL"/>
                <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/>
            </filter>
        </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_LOG"/>       
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: This does not show how to implement log4j.appender.SystemStatus